# Unable to assign ACL permissions to uploaded file when using S3FS node js lib

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, acl

I am using S3FS lib (in node.js app) to upload files to my AWS S3 directory. (referring documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3fs) and  [stackoverflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28081647/4349933)

s3fs object init
`s3fsImpl = new s3fs(bucketPath, {
            accessKeyId: xxxxx,
            secretAccessKey: xxxxx,
            ACL: 'public-read'
        })`

method writeFile: `s3fsImpl.writeFile(fileName, stream)`
file is uploaded successfully and I am getting "ETag" in response. However, uploaded file is not accessible publicly.

How can I give proper ACL permissions to make it accessible for public-read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I was able to get this working with following approach in node

Step 1:
Install and include "aws-sdk" to access aws resources (I used it for S3)

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
var s3 = new AWS.S3()
```

Step 2:

```
s3.putObject({
            Bucket: AWS_BUCKET_NAME, // bucket name on which file to be uploaded
            Key: uploadKey,  // file name on s3
            ContentType: file.type, // type of file
            Body: new Buffer(fileData, 'binary'), // base-64 file stream
            ACL: 'public-read'  // public read access
        }, function (err, resp) {
            if (err) {  // if there is any issue
                console.error('failed file upload to S3:: ', err)
                callback(err, null)
            }
            console.log('response from S3: ', resp)
            callback(null, 'Success')
        }
    )
```

**ACL: 'public-read'** will assign public-read access to your media/file on S3

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the ACL as the third option in `writeFile` method as

`s3fsImpl.writeFile(fileName, stream,{ ACL: 'public-read'})`