# Uploaded files to S3 bucket with Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been working on getting a node file to be able to handle uploads to an S3 bucket. So far I have been able to get it to create a bucket, but when I run a post request with postman, I cannot seem to upload the file. I have removed the accessKeyId and secret accessKey. Any luck doing this before?

```
var S3FS = require("s3fs");
var s3fsImpl = new S3FS('TestBucket12345', {
            accessKeyId:"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
            secretAccessKey:"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
});


s3fsImpl.create();

var multiparty = require("connect-multiparty"),
    multipartyMiddleware = multiparty;
module.exports = function(router, passport){
    router.use(multipartyMiddleware);

  router.post('/fileupload', function(req, res){
        var file = req.files.file;
        var stream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
        return s3fsImpl.writeFile(file.originalFilename, stream).then(function(){
            fs.unlink(file.path, function(err){
                if(err){
                console.log(err);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: So what's the error message? Any reason you are using `s3fs` instead of the official AWS SDK for NodeJS?

Comment: Note also that based on what you appear to be doing here, you want to `put`, not `post`.

Comment: Interesting Michael, I will try that out.

Comment: Mark, I was getting 404 unable to post to /fileupload. 
I was following a tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gv0PJrMDBYc and was trying this approach out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload a file to Amazon S3 with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018855/upload-a-file-to-amazon-s3-with-nodejs)